# How to use SSL with a WCF web service?

Tags: wcf, web-services, ssl

I have a web service in asp.net running and everything works fine. Now I need to access some methods in that web-service using SSL. It works perfect when I contact the web-service using http:// but with https:// I get "There was no endpoint listening at https://...".

Can you please help me on how to set up my web.config to support both http and https access to my web service. I have tried to follow guidelines but I can't get it working.

Some code:

My TestService.svc:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class TestService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public bool validUser(string email) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My Web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
                    <enableWebScript />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior" name="TestService">
                <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
                     binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceBinding"
                     contract="TestService" />
            </service>
        </services>
        <bindings>
            <webHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ServiceBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="1000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="1000000" maxStringContentLength="1000000" maxArrayLength="1000000" maxBytesPerRead="1000000" maxNameTableCharCount="1000000"/>
                </binding>
            </webHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Have you set up the SSL site in IIS correctly, to serve the same web site?

Comment: Retagged to include wcf.  I'm probably not the best person to answer this question, but beyond setting up IIS, I believe there are also settings in the config file to let WCF know which certificate to use.

Comment: @Brian but if it's a webhttpbinding then it's up to IIS to negotiate the certificate - WCF can't get involved until after that I think?

Comment: You can do a webhttpbinding without getting IIS involved (it can be hosted by a windows service).  Though it is probably safe to assume in this case that IIS is involved since they have decorated the service with the AspNetCompatibilityRequirements attribute.

Comment: That's not an "ASP.NET Web Service" - it's a WCF Service.

Comment: @Rup Yes, SSL is setup and works fine for all other parts of the website but not for the web service.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the **webHttpBinding**, try creating a **customBinding** instead:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="poxBindingHttps" closeTimeout="00:00:20">
        <textMessageEncoding writeEncoding="utf-8" />
        <httpsTransport manualAddressing="true"/>
    </binding>
    <binding name="poxBindingHttp" closeTimeout="00:00:20">
        <textMessageEncoding writeEncoding="utf-8" />
        <httpTransport manualAddressing="true"/>
    </binding>
</customBinding>
```

You'll also need to setup the **webHttpBehavior** like so:

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ajaxBehavior">
            <enableWebScript/>
            <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And finally, your service & endpoint:

```
<services>
    <service name="TestService">
        <endpoint name="sslDefault" address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="poxBindingHttps" behaviorConfiguration="ajaxBehavior" contract="TestService"/>
        <endpoint name="noSslDefault" address="" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="poxBindingHttp" behaviorConfiguration="ajaxBehavior" contract="TestService"/>
    </service>
</services>
```

Hopefully that works out for you in creating an SSL endpoint

Comment: Thanks! Shouldn't the behaviorConfiguration="webHttpBehavior" be behaviorConfiguration="ajaxBehavior"? And will this make my web service work for both HTTP and HTTPS?

Comment: Whoops, yeah. The behavior configuration should be ajaxBehavior. I will update my post to include support for both HTTP and HTTPS, although in the real world you should only have one or the other for your web service, not both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there is more an issue with IIS no listening on port 443 (The port used for HTTPS). Check IIS that there is a certificate installed and that it is listening on the secure port.

Comment: Thanks! But can that be the problem if HTTPS is working for the rest of the website?